# SQL server update locks complete table instead of single rows

Tags: sql-server, locking

Consider a simple table with an `Id` and `Item`:

```
Column  date type
------------------------
Id      int primary key
Item    varchar(50)
```

Insert three items:

```
INSERT INTO [Items] ([Item]) VALUES ('first item'); // Id 1
INSERT INTO [Items] ([Item]) VALUES ('seconditem'); // Id 2
INSERT INTO [Items] ([Item]) VALUES ('third item'); // Id 3
```

Now I update a single row in a transaction (which I explicitely don't commit for testing purposes):

```
// query 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE Items SET
  Item = 'updated'
WHERE Id = 2;
```

Now in parallel I run a second query:

```
// query 2
SELECT Id, Item From [Items];
```

`query 2` hangs indefinitely. I don't understand why. Shouldn't this query be independent of `query 1`, just reading committed data and ignoring the ongoing update? Any way to optimize/configure this? Or do I have to live with SQL Server blocking whole tables during updates?

Comment: Your second query doesn't have a `where` clause to filter to just `id = 1`, though that may not make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David Browne mentions, this is the default behavior of the default [**isolation level**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server. You can look into using alternative **isolation levels** such as `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

Also to clarify, `UPDATE` operations don't lock the entire table necessarily, in the default **isolation level**. In your example, likely only a **row level lock** is occuring on the row with `Id = 2` **but** because your second query requests that row (since it's selecting the entire table) it sits waiting on the lock for just the row with `Id = 2` before it can return any results. If you modified your test, so your second query said `SELECT Id, Item From [Items] WHERE Id = 1` then you'll likely get results instantly.

Comment: On the final sentence, that would only work if it *was* a row-lock. If it's a page-lock (which it very well may be) and the `SELECT` requests the same page, you still get blocking

Answer (score 2):

Turn on READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT if you want readers and writers to not block each other.

See: [Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels in the SQL Server Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#Row_versioning)